# ActsAsTaggableOn: Get all tags for child objects in a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

My rails app has institution-level accounts with many users.

Each Institution has many Projects.

A project acts_as_taggable and users at an institution can add tags to their institution's projects.

I would like to query for a list of all tags on Projects belonging to a specific institution.

e.g., something like `Project.where(institution_id: 1).tags` (which doesn't exist)

Do I need to set the project's institution as the owner of the tags to facilitate this and then query by owner?

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

Then when setting tags:

```
@current_user.institution.tag(@some_project, with: 'tag1, tag2')
```

...and getting the tags:

```
@current_user.institution.owned_tags
```

Or, is there an approach that does not require setting ownership?

Comment: Did you end up sorting this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, do something like:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.
  joins(:taggings).
  where(taggings: {taggable: current_institution.projects})
```

That syntax may require some tweaking (although, it works on my data).

I am assuming you have some way to get the projects belonging to an institution - which I've sort of waved at with `current_institution.projects`. Substitute as appropriate for your own code.

In any case, I believe that should head you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! That template led me straight to the answer. For **ActsAsTaggableOn** it worked as follows: `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(:taggings).where(taggings: { taggable_id: current_institution.projects })` I have other models that **act_as_taggable** so I limited the query to only projects with **taggable_type** as follows: `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(:taggings).where(taggings: { taggable_id: current_institution.projects, taggable_type: :Project })`

Comment: Sorry I mistyped `ActsAsTaggable` instead of `ActsAsTaggableOn`. Out of curiosity, did you try it the way I stated? I would have thought (but I might have mistaken) that doing `taggable: current_institution.projects` (not `taggable_id`) would have scoped it specifically to projects, saving you the `taggable_type:` statement.

Comment: Yup, I tried it the with `taggable: ...` but it wasn't smart enough. It complained that the column did not exist.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to go look at the source code. In any case, feel free to upvote if you like.